# Does everyone in the U.S. (and beyond?) pronounce "Buick" with the Spanish B/V, or is this a regional thing?

Tags: pronunciation

There's a long and dry story to this, so I'll just get to the point and ask the question:

Does everyone in the U.S. (and beyond?) pronounce the beginnng of the word "Buick" with the "Spanish" combination B/V sound, or is this a regional thing?

That is, when I hear people mention this make of car, it sounds as if they begin the word with a sound that is a cross between the letters B and V, so that you could just as easily think the person were saying either "View-ick" or "Byoo-
ick" but you're not sure which one they intend.

This is the only "English" (?) word I've ever noticed with its "B" being pronounced in the Spanish ("B = V = B", or "B = BV") fashion.

Is this a common anomaly (IOW, is it pronounced that way throughout the US or even the world)? If not, what is the usual way of pronouncing it? If what I've heard is a regionalism, how wide is that region (perhaps limited to northern 
California)?

Comment: I'm from the US Midwest and I've never heard anything but Byoo-ick.

Comment: I live in Upstate New York and have consistently heard the /b/ pronunciation.

Comment: Never heard of it being anything but Buick with a B. But then it is not a word much used in Britain because General Motors have never sold under that marque in Europe; preferring *Opel* in Germany and *Vauxhall* in Britain.

Comment: Maybe I should have turned the question around and asked if anyone but me had ever heard it that way...

Comment: @B.ClayShannon From the comments above, I think you have the answer to that question too. Where do you live? Is there a specific kind or class or category of people who pronounce the B in Buick this way? Do those same people pronounce any other Bs, or anything else, for that matter, oddly? Are any of them of Hispanic descent?

Comment: Spanish B is a fricative B, or [β]. /v/ is a fricative sound as well, so maybe that's why you hear them alike. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I've always assumed **buckaroo** to be the "Anglicized" version of [vaquero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaquero), which is written that way because Spanish speakers find initial /b/ difficult to articulate.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if some, say, Spanish speakers *hear* more of a V sound, even though a native English speaker, listening to the same sounds would not hear it that way.  This is often the case (as is the English speaker hearing a solid B when the actual sound is "borderline" between B and V).

Comment: I heard it that way long before I learned any Spanish.

Comment: You're not entirely off track here...a certain (Castillian) Spanish-speaking spousal unit pronounces the sport "volleyvall". :-)

Comment: By the way, some of the above information is incorrect. In Spanish, all initial b's and v's are pronounced [b], while intervocalic b's and v's are pronounced [β], which is between the English b and v sounds.  Word-initial b's and v's within word clusters, such as "la vaca" are pronounced with the intervocalic sound.  Kristina, your Castillian husband apparently learned to correct the initial sound but is still flummoxed by the intervocalic one.

Comment: @Yay watch your language! Well, I guess "fricative" is just a euphemism...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always heard it pronounced "Byoo-ick."  Without exception.  This also seems to agree: http://www.pronouncenames.com/pronounce/buick

Comment: Maybe my dad and uncles are the only ones in the world, then...but then again, they have some other "interesting" way of saying things (from a very remote part of northern California).

Comment: I'll add that "Buick" is an incredibly "American" word, one that virtually everyone in the US grew up knowing and hearing, advertised on radio and TV.  Even in regions with strong regional accents for other words, it would rarely be pronounced differently.  **Except** that, about 50 years ago, there was a family living on the block behind us that pronounced it "Booick".

Comment: Yes, I think the dialect I heard was English.American.Western.Californian.NorthernCalifornian.Rural.KettenpomValleyan.Shannonian

Comment: @HotLicks: Wouldn't you really rather have a Buick, a Buick, '65 Buick? https://www.google.com/search?q=wouldn%27t+you+really+rather+drive+a+Buick&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&oq=wouldn%27t+you+really+rather+drive+a+Buick&aqs=chrome..69i57.434537810j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:74d1d967,vid:oizl5KF0e2E

Answer (score 3):

I am a Buick ... we are Scottish,  originally so .. pronounced bue..ick, originating from Dundee, my relatives were obviously the car manufactures... but not that immediate family:)
My parents are from Perthshire....I was born in the highlands  and my history is from Viking to Jacobsen to present ...
I have known a few Bewicks after the queen''s swans ...
Everyone pronounces my name wrong.... I secretly appreciate having an unusual name .
Imogen Buick

Comment: Actually the swans were named after the engraver Thomas Bewick, author and illustrator of an early bird book.